# How to update ipyvolume shapes immediately without intermediate views

Tags: python, three.js, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Given jupyter notebook with a scene rendered with ipyvolume and sliders that updates the x,y,z traits of a shape on the scene, the 3D renderer has a scene change animation which draws intermediate views of the shape that do not correspond to views on the slider.

How do I force ipyvolume to render only the final scene on update, without the scene change animation?

For example, run the following in a jupyter notebook and drag theta/phi:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi, sin, cos, radians
import ipyvolume as ipv
import ipywidgets as widgets

def transform_xyz(theta, phi, x, y, z):
    x, y, z = [np.asarray(v) for v in (x, y, z)]
    shape = x.shape
    points = np.matrix([x.flatten(), y.flatten(), z.flatten()])
    Ry_theta = [[+cos(theta), 0, +sin(theta)],
                [0, 1, 0],
                [-sin(theta), 0, +cos(theta)]]
    Rz_phi = [[+cos(phi), -sin(phi), 0],
              [+sin(phi), +cos(phi), 0],
              [0, 0, 1]]
    points = np.matrix(Rz_phi)*np.matrix(Ry_theta)*points
    x, y, z = [np.array(v).reshape(shape) for v in points]
    return x, y, z

def torus(R=100, r=10, Rsteps=100, rsteps=100):
    u = np.linspace(0, 2*pi, rsteps) # tube
    v = np.linspace(0, 2*pi, Rsteps) # ring
    U, V = np.meshgrid(u, v)
    x = (R + r*cos(U))*cos(V)
    y = (R + r*cos(U))*sin(V)
    z = r*sin(U)
    return x, y, z

class Scene:
    def __init__(self, view=(0, 0, 0), hkl=(1,1,1)):
        self.view = view
        self.figure = ipv.figure()
        R = 100.
        r = R/30.
        ipv.xlim(-R, R)
        ipv.ylim(-R, R)
        ipv.zlim(-R, R)
        ipv.style.box_off()
        self.torus_xyz = torus(R=R, r=R/10)
        self.torus = ipv.plot_surface(*self.torus_xyz)
        ipv.show()
        self.ui = widgets.interact(self.update, theta=(-90.,90.), phi=(-180., 180.))
        #self.ui.widget.children[0].continuous_update = False
        #self.ui.widget.children[1].continuous_update = False

    def update(self, theta, phi):
        print("update with", theta, phi)
        x, y, z = transform_xyz(radians(theta), radians(phi), *self.torus_xyz)
        self.torus.x = x.flatten()
        self.torus.y = y.flatten()
        self.torus.z = z.flatten()

scene = Scene()
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You could also try setting the animation_exponent to 0. Ipyvolume uses linear interpolation to update the figure on a data change, the exponent sets the speed of this interpolation. A zero exponent should result in an instant update.

```
self.figure = ipv.figure(animation=0.,animation_exponent=0.)
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't change the behaviour with regard to the smoothness of the animation. I think for that I need to figure out how to synchronize trait updates to x, y, and z.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the animation time for the transition to zero when the figure is created mostly solves the problem:

```
...
self.figure = ipv.figure(animation=0.)
...
```

The figure still jitters a bit when ui sliders are set to continuous update, presumably because there is an occasional transition frame that is being drawn.

---

Another possible source of jitter is that traitlets is not sending x, y, z updates synchronously, and so maybe it is sometimes showing updates with x and y for the new view while retaining z from the old view.